# How to load an image from a file in Qt?

Tags: c++, image, qt, set

Generally, I've been searching for a while and could not find a serious answer. The problem is that I've a QString variable containing certain url, e.g. "C:/Users/Me/Desktop/image.png". How to open it and display the image in my application window?
I know the problem might seem trivial, however I can't find a working solution.

Answer (score 17):

Load the image by using `QPixmap` and then show it with `QLabel`:

```
QString url = R"(C:/Users/Me/Desktop/image.png)";
QPixmap img(url);
QLabel *label = new QLabel(this);
label->setPixmap(img);
```

[ImageViewer example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-imageviewer-example.html)

Comment: It is a raw string (introcuded in c++11). Don't pay attention to it since you already have a `QString` with the url so you don't need this line. I've just wrote it to be clear where the `url` comes from in my snippet. If you don't want to read manuals, you'll always get unpredictable behaviour (for yourself) in your program. You better read everything. Programming needs a lot of knowledges. While you may code something with some handbook, you'll never know will something work for you tomorrow if you don't go deeper in the theory and how it actually works.

Answer (score 4):

```
void LoadAvatar(const std::string &strAvatarUrl, QLabel &lable)
{ 
   QUrl url(QString().fromStdString(strAvatarUrl));
   QNetworkAccessManager manager;
   QEventLoop loop;

   QNetworkReply *reply = manager.get(QNetworkRequest(url));
   QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, &loop, [&reply, &lable,&loop](){
    if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
    {
        QByteArray jpegData = reply->readAll();
        QPixmap pixmap;
        pixmap.loadFromData(jpegData);
        if (!pixmap.isNull())
        {
            lable.clear();
            lable.setPixmap(pixmap);
        }
    }
    loop.quit();
  });

  loop.exec();
}
```